A set of five (one is missing!)
Find which car is missing and then tell me the 6-letter answer that describes this puzzle.



Did the picture render correctly?  The red car is straddling  the dividing line as are two of the inward pointing arrows.

@lulu Yes, everything is as it was intended to be.

Looks like the board game 'Man, Don't Get Angry!' :)

@Lezzup Had to Google that, it does, but no nothing to do with board games or similar. It depicts something else.

Just so you know... the knowledge required is, not trivial, but kinda basic and will hopefully make sense once you find the right approach.

At first I thought Ludo, haha. EDIT: Ohh, that's the same game as what Lezzup mentioned, just German version

@justhalf, I was thinking of 'Mens, erger je niet', how we Dutch call it. I had to google for the english name, before commenting ;)

The car that is missing is:

 A blue car which should be positioned so as to follow the red car at centre-top.

Why? Because:

 The route that each of these cars takes if it follows the arrows ahead of it will form the shape of a Nordic cross used in national flags.



 Three of them carry out a cross-shaped lap of the whole circuit:

 - The yellow car makes the thick yellow Nordic cross from the flag of Sweden.
 - The blue car currently in position makes the thick blue Nordic cross from the flag of Finland.
 - The white car makes the thick white Nordic cross from the flags of Denmark, Norway and Iceland.

 The other traces out a 'thinner' cross shape:

 - The red car makes the thin red Nordic cross from the flag of Iceland. (By going from top to bottom, back up to the middle, then left, then all the way right...)

So what's missing is..

 ...a similarly positioned blue car to make the thin blue Nordic cross from the flag of Norway. All suggesting our 6-letter word is NORDIC!

PS

 The OP mentions in comments that while my final answer is apt, actually their intended 6-letter answer was simply the identity of the missing country, NORWAY, since the use of roads ("WAYs") to clue NORdic countries makes this puzzle nicely thematic that way (NOR-WAY)...


Gahh I was sooo close! I literally had a web page up of countries with crosses in their flags, but still couldn’t find the group of 5 then gave up ! Good solve

Well done! :) One thing though, the final answer I had in mind also described the puzzle overall and actually is the missing one. Rot13(Abejnl npghnyyl zrnaf abegurea jnl. Juvpu guvf chmmyr qrcvpgf... Abeqvp pbhagevrf ba gur jnl (ba gur ebnq). That's why I intentionally left it out of the puzzle because I thought it described the puzzle well. Yours work too ofc but then it makes more sense that it should've been included in the puzzle.

@Prim3numbah Aha, I'll add your intentions too in that case :)
